# deleting arrays during run time in C++ to spare some memory

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a C++ script running with a C++98 version on a microcontroller ( No upgrade is possible). In this script I need to initialize two vectors of doubles of 405 already existing elements each. I tried initializating two arrays : `double a[405]= {7.05925826e+07, ...};` and `double b [405]= {arr[0], arr[0]*arr[1]...};`. `a[405]` is defined in the following way:

```
double a[405] = {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17], a[18], a[19], a[20], a[21], a[22], a[23], a[24], a[25], a[26], a[0]*a[0], a[0]*a[1], a[0]*a[2], a[0]*a[3], a[0]*a[4], a[0]*a[5], a[0]*a[6], a[0]*a[7], a[0]*a[8], a[0]*a[9], a[0]*a[10], a[0]*a[11], a[0]*a[12], a[0]*a[13], a[0]*a[14], a[0]*a[15], a[0]*a[16], a[0]*a[17], a[0]*a[18], a[0]*a[19], a[0]*a[20], a[0]*a[21], a[0]*a[22], a[0]*a[23], a[0]*a[24], a[0]*a[25], a[0]*a[26], a[1]*a[1], a[1]*a[2], a[1]*a[3], a[1]*a[4], a[1]*a[5], a[1]*a[6], a[1]*a[7], a[1]*a[8], a[1]*a[9], a[1]*a[10], a[1]*a[11], a[1]*a[12], a[1]*a[13], a[1]*a[14], a[1]*a[15], a[1]*a[16], a[1]*a[17], a[1]*a[18], a[1]*a[19], a[1]*a[20], a[1]*a[21], a[1]*a[22], a[1]*a[23], a[1]*a[24], a[1]*a[25], a[1]*a[26], a[2]*a[2], a[2]*a[3], a[2]*a[4], a[2]*a[5], a[2]*a[6], a[2]*a[7], a[2]*a[8], a[2]*a[9], a[2]*a[10], a[2]*a[11], a[2]*a[12], a[2]*a[13], a[2]*a[14], a[2]*a[15], a[2]*a[16], a[2]*a[17], a[2]*a[18], a[2]*a[19], a[2]*a[20], a[2]*a[21], a[2]*a[22], a[2]*a[23], a[2]*a[24], a[2]*a[25], a[2]*a[26], a[3]*a[3], a[3]*a[4], a[3]*a[5], a[3]*a[6], a[3]*a[7], a[3]*a[8], a[3]*a[9], a[3]*a[10], a[3]*a[11], a[3]*a[12], a[3]*a[13], a[3]*a[14], a[3]*a[15], a[3]*a[16], a[3]*a[17], a[3]*a[18], a[3]*a[19], a[3]*a[20], a[3]*a[21], a[3]*a[22], a[3]*a[23], a[3]*a[24], a[3]*a[25], a[3]*a[26], a[4]*a[4], a[4]*a[5], a[4]*a[6], a[4]*a[7], a[4]*a[8], a[4]*a[9], a[4]*a[10], a[4]*a[11], a[4]*a[12], a[4]*a[13], a[4]*a[14], a[4]*a[15], a[4]*a[16], a[4]*a[17], a[4]*a[18], a[4]*a[19], a[4]*a[20], a[4]*a[21], a[4]*a[22], a[4]*a[23], a[4]*a[24], a[4]*a[25], a[4]*a[26], a[5]*a[5], a[5]*a[6], a[5]*a[7], a[5]*a[8], a[5]*a[9], a[5]*a[10], a[5]*a[11], a[5]*a[12], a[5]*a[13], a[5]*a[14], a[5]*a[15], a[5]*a[16], a[5]*a[17], a[5]*a[18], a[5]*a[19], a[5]*a[20], a[5]*a[21], a[5]*a[22], a[5]*a[23], a[5]*a[24], a[5]*a[25], a[5]*a[26], a[6]*a[6], a[6]*a[7], a[6]*a[8], a[6]*a[9], a[6]*a[10], a[6]*a[11], a[6]*a[12], a[6]*a[13], a[6]*a[14], a[6]*a[15], a[6]*a[16], a[6]*a[17], a[6]*a[18], a[6]*a[19], a[6]*a[20], a[6]*a[21], a[6]*a[22], a[6]*a[23], a[6]*a[24], a[6]*a[25], a[6]*a[26], a[7]*a[7], a[7]*a[8], a[7]*a[9], a[7]*a[10], a[7]*a[11], a[7]*a[12], a[7]*a[13], a[7]*a[14], a[7]*a[15], a[7]*a[16], a[7]*a[17], a[7]*a[18], a[7]*a[19], a[7]*a[20], a[7]*a[21], a[7]*a[22], a[7]*a[23], a[7]*a[24], a[7]*a[25], a[7]*a[26], a[8]*a[8], a[8]*a[9], a[8]*a[10], a[8]*a[11], a[8]*a[12], a[8]*a[13], a[8]*a[14], a[8]*a[15], a[8]*a[16], a[8]*a[17], a[8]*a[18], a[8]*a[19], a[8]*a[20], a[8]*a[21], a[8]*a[22], a[8]*a[23], a[8]*a[24], a[8]*a[25], a[8]*a[26], a[9]*a[9], a[9]*a[10], a[9]*a[11], a[9]*a[12], a[9]*a[13], a[9]*a[14], a[9]*a[15], a[9]*a[16], a[9]*a[17], a[9]*a[18], a[9]*a[19], a[9]*a[20], a[9]*a[21], a[9]*a[22], a[9]*a[23], a[9]*a[24], a[9]*a[25], a[9]*a[26], a[10]*a[10], a[10]*a[11], a[10]*a[12], a[10]*a[13], a[10]*a[14], a[10]*a[15], a[10]*a[16], a[10]*a[17], a[10]*a[18], a[10]*a[19], a[10]*a[20], a[10]*a[21], a[10]*a[22], a[10]*a[23], a[10]*a[24], a[10]*a[25], a[10]*a[26], a[11]*a[11], a[11]*a[12], a[11]*a[13], a[11]*a[14], a[11]*a[15], a[11]*a[16], a[11]*a[17], a[11]*a[18], a[11]*a[19], a[11]*a[20], a[11]*a[21], a[11]*a[22], a[11]*a[23], a[11]*a[24], a[11]*a[25], a[11]*a[26], a[12]*a[12], a[12]*a[13], a[12]*a[14], a[12]*a[15], a[12]*a[16], a[12]*a[17], a[12]*a[18], a[12]*a[19], a[12]*a[20], a[12]*a[21], a[12]*a[22], a[12]*a[23], a[12]*a[24], a[12]*a[25], a[12]*a[26], a[13]*a[13], a[13]*a[14], a[13]*a[15], a[13]*a[16], a[13]*a[17], a[13]*a[18], a[13]*a[19], a[13]*a[20], a[13]*a[21], a[13]*a[22], a[13]*a[23], a[13]*a[24], a[13]*a[25], a[13]*a[26], a[14]*a[14], a[14]*a[15], a[14]*a[16], a[14]*a[17], a[14]*a[18], a[14]*a[19], a[14]*a[20], a[14]*a[21], a[14]*a[22], a[14]*a[23], a[14]*a[24], a[14]*a[25], a[14]*a[26], a[15]*a[15], a[15]*a[16], a[15]*a[17], a[15]*a[18], a[15]*a[19], a[15]*a[20], a[15]*a[21], a[15]*a[22], a[15]*a[23], a[15]*a[24], a[15]*a[25], a[15]*a[26], a[16]*a[16], a[16]*a[17], a[16]*a[18], a[16]*a[19], a[16]*a[20], a[16]*a[21], a[16]*a[22], a[16]*a[23], a[16]*a[24], a[16]*a[25], a[16]*a[26], a[17]*a[17], a[17]*a[18], a[17]*a[19], a[17]*a[20], a[17]*a[21], a[17]*a[22], a[17]*a[23], a[17]*a[24], a[17]*a[25], a[17]*a[26], a[18]*a[18], a[18]*a[19], a[18]*a[20], a[18]*a[21], a[18]*a[22], a[18]*a[23], a[18]*a[24], a[18]*a[25], a[18]*a[26], a[19]*a[19], a[19]*a[20], a[19]*a[21], a[19]*a[22], a[19]*a[23], a[19]*a[24], a[19]*a[25], a[19]*a[26], a[20]*a[20], a[20]*a[21], a[20]*a[22], a[20]*a[23], a[20]*a[24], a[20]*a[25], a[20]*a[26], a[21]*a[21], a[21]*a[22], a[21]*a[23], a[21]*a[24], a[21]*a[25], a[21]*a[26], a[22]*a[22], a[22]*a[23], a[22]*a[24], a[22]*a[25], a[22]*a[26], a[23]*a[23], a[23]*a[24], a[23]*a[25], a[23]*a[26], a[24]*a[24], a[24]*a[25], a[24]*a[26], a[25]*a[25], a[25]*a[26], a[26]*a[26]};
```

and then converting them using this function:

```
std::vector<double > ArrayToVector(double* arr, size_t arr_len) {
return std::vector<double>(arr, arr + arr_len);
}

std::vector<double> vec1= ArrayToVector(a,405);
std::vector<double> vec2= ArrayToVector(b,405);
```

The conversion of the arrays into a vectors causes memory problems. I am looking for a way to delete the first array `a[405]` just after converting it to vector in order to spare some memory for the second array conversion. I tried using `new` operator but that didn't work for me . Any other solution to reduce memory usage is appreciated.
Then I use a[] and b[] to calculate their scalar product using this function:

```
double scalar_product(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b)
{
    if( a.size() != b.size() ) // error check
    {
        //puts( "Error a's size not equal to b's size" ) ;
        return -1 ;  // not defined
    }
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= a.size() - 1; i++)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}
```

Comment: cant you use delete http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/

Comment: @RisingSun can you please show me an example how to use `new` and `delete` in that case. I am a beginner in C++

Comment: Show more code. How's `a[]` defined etc.

Comment: If memory is limited, why do you need to convert the existing arrays to `vector` at all?  And if you must, you don't actually need the `ArrayToVector()` function at all, since you are using a C++ version that doesn't guarantee temporaries are not created while calling that function. Just construct the `vector`s directly instead: `std::vector<double> vec1(a,a+405); std::vector<double> vec2(b,b+405);`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just a slightly edited repost of your earlier one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541171/is-there-a-way-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c98-without-requiring-much-memory Keep one, and edit it to contain all the info you have.#

Comment: @JHBonarius I added the definition of `a[]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I convert arrays to vectors because I need the scalar product of `a[]` and `b[]`

Comment: @underscore_d in the previous question I asked how to initialize vectors in C++98 and now I am asking about dynamic memory

Comment: @makz You don't need to convert the arrays to `vector` to do that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I do it then?

Comment: @makz Anything you can do with a `vector<T>`'s data, you can also do with a plain `T[]` array's data. Why do you think you need to convert `T[]` to `vector<T>` just to process the data?  All your scalar algorithm needs is a pointer to the data, and the size of the data, and you have that info with both a `T[]` array and a `vector<T>`. If you have an algorithm that takes `vector<T>` as input, change it to work with `T*`+`size` instead, or iterators.  Then you can support both containers

Comment: In retrospect, I should've voted to close the earlier one, and keep this, since this has more info and the updated question / problem statement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the function I use to calculate the scalar product. What do I need to change except `std::vector<double> a` to double `a` and same for `b`

Comment: @makz You _don't_ have a C++ "script" because C++ is a compiled language, not a scripting language.

Comment: @makz see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 3):

As some people have already suggested in comments, you don't really need to convert your arrays to vectors - just work directly with the arrays. All you need to add is the size of the arrays as a third parameter to your function. For that you obviously need to know the size, but since this is running on a microcontroller, where memory budget is tight, I'm relatively certain that you have access to the size info. So it could look like:

```
double scalar_product(double a[], double b[], unsigned int size)
{
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}
```

I'm assuming that their sizes are the same (they should) but even if not, you could use this to calculate a (partial) scalar product for two differently sized arrays, by supplying the shorter one's size.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating your `double[]` arrays *dynamically* via `new[]`, so they cannot be freed dynamically.  They are being declared in *automatic memory*, so they will be freed only when they go out of scope.

Since you are concerned with limited memory usage, your best option is to simply not convert your `double[]` arrays to `std::vector<double>` at all. Change your `scalar_product()` function instead so it can handle the original `double[]` arrays as-is, eg:

```cpp
double scalar_product(const double *a, size_t a_size, const double *b, size_t b_size)
{
    if( a_size != b_size ) // error check
    {
        //puts( "Error a's size not equal to b's size" ) ;
        return -1 ;  // not defined
    }
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_size; ++i)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}

double a[405] = ...;
double b[405] = ...;
double product = scalar_product(a, 405, b, 405);

/*
if, for some reason, you also needed to get the product of vectors,
you can do this:

double scalar_product(const std::vector<double> &a, const std::vector<double> &b)
{
    return scalar_product(&a[0], a.size(), &b[0], b.size());
}

vector<double> a = ...;
vector<double> b = ...;
double product = scalar_product(a, b);
*/
```

Or:

```cpp
double scalar_product(const double *a, const double *b, size_t n)
{
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}

double a[405] = ...;
double b[405] = ...;
double product = scalar_product(a, b, 405);

/*
if, for some reason, you also needed to get the product of vectors,
you can do this:

double scalar_product(const std::vector<double> &a, const std::vector<double> &b)
{
    return (a.size() == b.size())
        ? scalar_product(&a[0], &b[0], a.size())
        : -1.0;
}

vector<double> a = ...;
vector<double> b = ...;
double product = scalar_product(a, b);
*/
```

Alternatively, you can let the compiler deduce the array sizes for you, if you are passing in the original arrays directly, and not passing in pointers to the arrays:

```cpp
template<size_t a_size, size_t b_size>
double scalar_product(const double (&a)[a_size], const double (&b)[b_size])
{
    if( a_size != b_size ) // error check
    {
        //puts( "Error a's size not equal to b's size" ) ;
        return -1 ;  // not defined
    }
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_size; ++i)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}

double a[405] = ...;
double b[405] = ...;
double product;

product = scalar_product(a, b); // OK

double *pa = a;
double *pb = b;
product = scalar_product(pa, pb); // COMPILER ERROR

/*
this approach doesn't work with vectors, so you will need a
separate overload of scalar_product() for that...
*/
```

Or:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
double scalar_product(const double (&a)[N], const double (&b)[N])
{
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}

double a[405] = ...;
double b[405] = ...;
double product;

product = scalar_product(a, b); // OK

double c[404] = ...;
double d[405] = ...;

product = scalar_product(c, d); // COMPILER ERROR

/*
this approach doesn't work with vectors, so you will need a
separate overload of scalar_product() for that...
*/
```

Otherwise, if the array size is constant at compile-time, then just hard-code it:

```cpp
const size_t ArrSize = 405;

double scalar_product(const double (&a)[ArrSize], const double (&b)[ArrSize])
{
    // compute
    double product = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ArrSize; ++i)
        product += (a[i])*(b[i]); // += means add to product
    return product;
}

double a[ArrSize] = ...;
double b[ArrSize] = ...;
double product = scalar_product(a, b);

/*
this approach doesn't work with vectors, so you will need a
separate overload of scalar_product() for that...
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

An array must be dynamically allocated (using the `new[]` operator) in order to use the `delete[]` operator to free it. As the comments have mentioned, you should post how you create your arrays so we can get a better understanding of how they are stored in memory.

```cpp
double a* = new double[size];
// do stuff with a
delete[] a;
```

The above example is legal and will do what you asked.

Comment: And how can I initialize the elements of the arrays?

Comment: Using `new[]`, you can't initialize the array with values on the `new[]` statement in C++98. You will have to use `a[index] = ...` for each element individually, or else use `memcpy()`/`std::copy()` from another array.